# Непонятная ошибка при чтении файла

Tags: python

**Файл Main.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qw
import PyQt5.QtCore as qc
import PyQt5.QtGui as qg

#   Инициализация словарей
Name = {}

#   Инициализация настроек
with open('Settings.ini') as file: exec(file.read())


class MainWindow(qw.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mwidget = qw.QMainWindow(self)
        #self.setWindowFlags(qc.Qt.Tool | qc.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | qc.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setGeometry(qc.QRect(100, 100, 200, 200))

        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Файл Settings.ini:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Name[16] = "Изменение библиотечного элемента"
```

**Проблема:**

При запуске через отладчик PyScrypter, пишет все ок, и показывает окно, но
при запуске двойным щелчком ничего не открывается.

**Собственно ошибка:**

Не может прочитать слово 'Изменение', а точнее заглавную букву 'И' хз почему... Другие рускоязычные слова читает, пробелы не влияют, длина строки не влияет, как только убираю это слово, все начинает работать. Подскажите что не так???

Почему отладчик PyScripter выводит : "Изменение библиотечного элемента",
а двойной щелчок : "Р·РјРµРЅРµРЅРёРµ Р±РёР±Р»РёРѕС‚РµС‡РЅРѕРіРѕ СЌР»РµРјРµРЅС‚Р°" ????

Команды не помогают:

```
with open('Settings.ini', encoding="cp1251/utf-8") as file: exec(file.read())
```

Comment: `cp1251/utf-8` а так разве можно? :D Попробуйте одну кодировку указывать, например: `with open('Settings.ini', encoding="utf-8") as file: exec(file.read())`

Comment: Пробовал отдельно и то и то. на форуме просто писать еще строку не хотелось, прошу прощения, что ввел в заблуждение.

Comment: gil9red, Да, я уже сам дошел до этого... Но спасибо. сейчас ответ напишу.

Comment: попробуйте вон ту штуку https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Comment: Интик, пробовал, не зашло, много проблем, тем более с комментариями. а так загрузил как кусок кода и все...

Answer (score 1):

Проблема с кодировкой. Решение такое:
1)

```
with open('Settings.ini', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    exec(file.read())
```

2) файл `Settings.ini` обязательно в кодировке `utf-8`.

(p.s. Лично у меня иначе отказывалось запускаться.)